# mui card is making extra right space on page with cardMedia

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I got a card in a grid. when i have this card without cardMedia having an image page is fine. but when i add this cardMedia media with an image i am getting a horizontal scroll bar down the page which is showing extra space on the right side of page.

```
      <Grid container spacing={2} sx={{ mt: "35px" }}>
        <Grid item xs={12} md={8}>
          <Card sx={{ mb: "10px", padding: "2vw",}}>
            <CardMedia
              component="img"
              src={ebs}
              alt="EBS Image"
              sx={{
                objectFit: "cover",
                maxWidth: "20px",
              }} 
            />
          </Card>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
```

even this is giving that extra space / scrollbar .
i tried with 20 px for height and width , tried to hide scrollbar none worked.